# C++ Program won't build. Getting Undefined symbols for architecture error

Tags: c++, gcc, architecture, build, linker

I am learning C++ and were are just going over classes.

I thought I had created everything correctly, but when I try and clean/build the code I get an error:

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .clean-conf
rm -f -r build/Debug
rm -f dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/hw4


CLEAN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 57ms)

"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/hw4
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX
rm -f build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/karavites_william_oct7_homework.o.d
g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/karavites_william_oct7_homework.o.d -o build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/karavites_william_oct7_homework.o karavites_william_oct7_homework.cpp
karavites_william_oct7_homework.cpp: In function 'void insertAtEnd(int)':
karavites_william_oct7_homework.cpp:85: warning: NULL used in arithmetic
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX
rm -f build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o.d
g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o.d -o build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o main.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX
g++     -o dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/hw4 build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/karavites_william_oct7_homework.o build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "BookList::printerr()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/hw4] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 469ms)
```

I have 3 files in the project:

- main.cpp
- karavites_william_oct7_homework.cpp
- karavites_william_oct7_homework.h

I have the functions and class defined in the header file and a simple method in the class (class.cpp) file that just prints out a string to test everything.

This is what my main file looks like that calls/creates the class:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "karavites_william_oct7_homework.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int ch;

/*
 * 
 */


int getNum(int cho) {
    int ans;
    switch (cho) {
        case 1: cout << "Please type in the ISBN you wish to search\\insert\\delete\n";
            cin >> ans;
            break;
        case 2: cout << "Please type in the position of the element you wish to delete/insert\n";
            cin >> ans;
            break;
    }

    return ans;

}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    BookList bl;


    bl.printerr();

    return 0;
}
```

**class1.h**

```
/* 
 * File:   karavites_william_oct7_homework.h
 * Author: willkara
 *
 * Created on October 7, 2013, 9:21 PM
 */



#ifndef KARAVITES_WILLIAM_OCT7_HOMEWORK_H
#define KARAVITES_WILLIAM_OCT7_HOMEWORK_H
#include <vector>

class BookList {
public:
    BookList();


    void insertAtEnd(int new_element);
    void insertAtLocation(int new_element, int pos);
    int linSearch(int isbn);
    int binSearch(int element);
    void deleteByPosition(int position);
    void deleteByItem(int item);
    void printerr();

    void print();
    int menu();
    int countCurrent();
    void bubbleSort();
    void fixNulls();
    void selectionSort();

private:

    static int lSize;

    int bList[20];
    bool sorted;
    int p;

};

#endif  /* KARAVITES_WILLIAM_OCT7_HOMEWORK_H */
```

The booklist class has a bunch of methods, but I can't even get a simple one that prints out a line to work.

```
#include "karavites_william_oct7_homework.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int bList[20];
int lSize = 20;
bool sorted;
int c;

BookList::BookList() {

}


void printerr() {
    cout << "I will hopefully work this time.\n";
}
```

Am I missing a declaration somewhere? I am using NetBeans 7.3.1 on a mac OSX 10.7.5 to develop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be:

```
void BookList::printerr() {
    cout << "I will hopefully work this time.\n";
}
```

Notice the `BookList::`, i.e. you forgot to specify the class to which the method belongs during its implementation/definition. As a result, compiler thinks that this is just a global function `printerr`, but you call it inside `main` as a method of class, hence the compiler cannot find an implementation of `BookList::printerr` during linking stage and reports the error.

An important remark on terminology (which you've intermixed in comments), **declaration** of method is this:

```
class BookList {
    ...

    void printerr();

    ...
};
```

I.e. the method is just declared, not defined/implemented.

**Definition/implementation** of method is this:

```
void BookList::printerr() {
    ...
}
```

And this is both **declaration** and **definition/implementation** altogether:

```
class BookList {
    ...

    void printerr() {
        ...
    }

    ...
};
```

In this case you would not need to specify `BookList::` since the compiler already knows that you define/implement the `printerr` method inside the `BookList` class.

Comment: So the class name + :: has to be included in every method declaration?

Comment: Since you want this method to belong to the class, then during its implementation you should explicitly state it somehow, otherwise compiler thinks that this is just a global function `printerr`.

Comment: You don't need the class-name in the declarations in the header as they're inside the 'class Booklist {}' which shows they're part of the class, but yes you need to include this when writing your definitions in the separate .cpp file, as it has no way of otherwise knowing that the printerr function is the same one under BookList as was declared in the header rather than just a freestanding function unrelated to the BookList class.